# Is it possible to program function into Qt's SLOT() for QWidget or should use QSignalMapper?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, signals-slots, slot

In my Qt Application I am dynamically creating 'Questions' in QVBoxLayouts for a 'Questionnaire'. There are 3 types of Questions: Boolean, Text, & Radio.

When the user 'adds a question' to the questionnaire, they are presented with a QComboBox. When the index/text of this QComboBox is edited, I want to act upon the SIGNAL emitted.

I would like to have something like Java's (from an old Android Project):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code to run...
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to have the same in Qt/C++ like:

```
connect(qvectorOfComboBoxes.at(qvectorOfComboBoxes.end()), SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),
            this, SLOT(
                    void comboBoxTextChanged(QString newComboxBoxText)
                    {
                        //This doesn't work
                    } )) ;
```

I understand from another post on here the [ideal approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173846/1312555) is a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details), but was hoping to perform the task in a manner similar to above.

Usually, I find my answers either on here or from a related Google search (I am probably searching the wrong thing as I don't know the name for this), and so was hoping somebody here could give me a yay or nay. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt5 and using a C++11-enabled compiler, you can use [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as slots, as [explained here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#2f49cd0d473b52e6ddb8b377a34e6c36):

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(signal(QString)), [](QString newComboxBoxText) {
    // add your code here
});
```

Otherwise, you can use `sender()` to query the `QObject*` which sent the signal, if this is enough information you need. To cast it to a `QComboBox*` please use `qobject_cast<QComboBox*>` and `Q_ASSERT` that it's not null. (You can't get a compile-time error that it was connected to some other type.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the correct terminology! I am just about to test it, I will mark this as the answer in a moment.