# How to set signal check for list of check box objects dynamically?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have list of check box objects which was created dynamically (runtime).
Now how can i set signal check for all these objects in runtime?
I'm using pyqt4 for developing.
i tried 'for loop' with objects, but signal check is set only to last object of that list. But i need to set signal check for all objects.

```
obj = widget()
count = 0
while(count<4):
        self.listOfObjs.append(QtGui.QCheckBox(obj.gridFrame))
        obj.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listOfObjs[count], count, 1)
        count = count + 1
for i in listOfObjs:
    i.stateChanged.connect(self.change)

def change():
     *****DO NECCESSARY THINGS*****
```

Comment: For me the code you show is correct, I think the error is elsewhere, you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could show more code, please.

Comment: understandable ? @eyllanesc

Comment: try Change `QtGui.QCheckBox(obj.gridFrame)` to `QtGui.QCheckBox(obj.gridFrame, obj)` As many times the garbage collector eliminates variables.

Comment: Also try changing to `def change(state):`

Comment: This is all I can suggest as I see that you can not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Got following error:TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call: QCheckBox(QWidget parent=None): too many arguments QCheckBox(QString, QWidget parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QFrame'

Comment: If your code was an mvce I could copy your code and execute it without any problem, but that is not your case.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173153/qt-dynamic-widgets-signal-and-slot-connection?rq=1